# Stone-Weierstrass: Summary

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

*This is just a summary.*

**Theorem**

Given a compact domain $\Omega$.

Regard the function space:
$$\mathcal{C}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}):=\{f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}:f^{-1}\mathcal{T}(\mathbb{R})\subseteq\mathcal{T}(\Omega)\}$$

Denote for shorthand:
$$\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{C}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}):\quad\mathcal{F}[x]:=\{f(x):f\in\mathcal{F}\}$$

Then separating algebras with identity are dense:
$$1\in\mathcal{A}\leq\mathcal{C}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}):\quad\mathcal{A}[x]\neq\mathcal{A}[y]\quad(x\neq y)\implies\overline{\mathcal{A}}=\mathcal{C}(\Omega,\mathbb{R})$$
This follows from the lemma and the proposition below.

**Remark**

How does this extend to the complex version?

**Corollary**

Polynomials on a compact euclidean domain are dense!

**Proposition**

Consider a lattice that satisfies:
$$\mathcal{L}\preccurlyeq\mathcal{L}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}):\quad l\in\mathcal{L}\implies \lambda l,\lambda+l\in\mathcal{L}$$

Then a separating one was already dense:
$$\mathcal{L}[x]\neq\mathcal{L}[y]\quad(x\neq y)\implies\overline{\mathcal{L}}=\mathcal{C}(\Omega,\mathbb{R})$$
That is a check step by step.

**Lemma**

The modulus can be approximated by polynomials:
$$M(t):=|t|:\quad\|M-P_n\|_{[-1,1]}\to0\quad(P_n\in\mathcal{P}[-1,1])$$
Alternatively one can approximate the square root:
$$R(s):=\sqrt{1-s}:\quad\|R-Q_n\|_{[0,1]}\to0\quad(Q_n\in\mathcal{P}[0,1])$$
*(For a detailed check see: [Modulus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1166386/79762))*

**Proof**

Clearly, all algebraic properties remain:
$$1\in\overline{\mathcal{A}}\leq\mathcal{C}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}):\quad \overline{\mathcal{A}}[x]\neq\overline{\mathcal{A}}[y]\quad(x\neq y)$$

In particular, it is a lattice then since:
$$f\neq0:\quad f\in\overline{\mathcal{A}}\implies P_n(f)\in\overline{\mathcal{A}}\implies|f|\in\overline{\mathcal{A}}\quad(\|f\|\leq1)$$
That proves the assertion.

**Credits**

Thanks alot for suggesting me Royden, T.A.E.!!

**Disclaimer**

This thread is meant to record. See: [Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer is community wiki.*

Suppose it is additional selfadjoint:
$$\mathcal{A}\leq\mathcal{C}(\Omega,\mathbb{C}):\quad\mathcal{A}^*=\mathcal{A}$$

Reduce to the real case by:
$$1\in\mathcal{A}_\mathbb{R}:=\{g\in\mathcal{A}:g=g^*\}\leq\mathcal{C}(\Omega,\mathbb{R})$$

This remains separating as:
$$g_x(x)\neq g_y(y)\quad(x\neq y)\implies\Re{g_x}(x)\neq\Re{g_y}(y)\lor\Im{g_x}(x)\neq\Im{g_y}(y)$$

So applying the real version gives:
$$g\in\mathcal{C}(\Omega,\mathbb{C}):\quad f_n+if'_n\to\Re{g}+i\Im{g}=g\quad(f_n,f'_n\in\mathcal{A}_\mathbb{R})$$

That extends the above result!