# Stone Weierstrass: Modulus

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Given the

Consider the modulus:
$$M(t):=|t|\quad(-1\leq t\leq1)$$

Introduce the square root:
$$R(s):=\sqrt{1-s}\quad(0\leq s\leq1)$$

They are related by:
$$M(t)=R(1-t^2)$$

Regard the binomial series expansion:
$$Q_K(s):=1-\frac12s-\frac12\frac12\frac{1}{2!}s^2-\ldots-\propto s^K=1-\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{(2k)!}{2k!}\frac{1}{(k+1)!}s^{k+1}$$

How to prove that it is a uniform approximation:
$$\|R-Q_K\|_{[0,1]}:=\sup_{s\in[0,1]}|R(s)-Q_K(s)|\stackrel{K\to\infty}{\to}0$$
*(On strictly smaller disks this follows by Taylor's theorem.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Binomial series for $(1-t)^{-1/2}$ about $t=0$ is
$$
\begin{align}
      \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}} & =1+\frac{1}{2}t+\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{2}\frac{t^{2}}{2!}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{2}\frac{5}{2}\frac{t^{3}}{2}+\cdots \\
             & = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(1/2+n)}{\Gamma(1/2)n!}t^{n},
     \;\;\;\; -1 < t < 1.
\end{align}
$$
This series converges uniformly on compact subsets of $(-1,1)$. So one is allowed to integrate over $[0,t]$ to obtain
$$
          -2\sqrt{1-t}+2=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(1/2+n)}{\Gamma(1/2)(n+1)!}t^{n+1},\;\;\; -1 < t < 1.
$$
Because the two sides are equal and the left is bounded as $t\uparrow 1$, the sum on the right remains similarly bounded. It follows that the sum converges when $t=1$, and
$$
        1 = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(1/2+n)}{\Gamma(1/2)(n+1)!}.
$$
That guarantees the uniform convergence of
$$
                       \sqrt{1-t}=1-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(1/2+n)}{\Gamma(1/2)(n+1)!}t^{n+1},\;\;\; -1 \le t \le 1.
$$